# Don't understand calling method with argument passed

Tags: java

```
package javaapplication1;

public class PassString {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      String name = "Shakespeare";

      System.out.println("In main, the name is "
              + name);

      changeName(name); // i don't get why we pass name as an argument

      System.out.println("Back in main, the name is "
              + name);
  }

  public static void changeName(String str) {
      str = "Dickens";

      System.out.println("In changeName, the name " + "is now "
              + str);
  }
}
```

I don't understand the purpose of passing name as an argument in the changeName method. Is it in any way related to String name = "Shakespeare";

Comment: I think it's trying to demonstrate the use of Java's pass by value arguments.  That is, any change to the parameter `str` is not reflected in the method calling it

Comment: Yeah. One might think `name` becomes `"Dickens"` after `changeName()`'s execution. But that does not happen in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of the example (I believe) is to show that Java uses pass-by-value semantics.

The *value* of the `name` variable in `main` is passed (by value) to `changeName`. That receives the value as the initial value of the parameter `str`.

The value of `str` is then changed to a reference to the string "Dickens", and that change is validated by the diagnostic at the end of the method.

However, when we get back to the `main` method, the next diagnostic line shows that the value of `name` hasn't changed. If Java used true pass-by-reference, changing `str` would also have changed `name` - but it didn't, because Java uses pass-by-value.

Comment: Great. Makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The point here is that even though you change the value of `str` in `changeName` to "Dickens", the variable `name` in `main()` is not affected.

Answer (score -2):

> I don't understand the purpose of passing name as an argument in the changeName method.

Looks like you are trying to change the value of `name` variable.

you should do it as follows:

```
// in main
name = changeName(name); 

// see the change in signature
public static String changeName(String str)
{
    String newName =  "William " + str;
    return newName;
}
```

> Why value of `name` is not changed?

Java is Pass-by-value.

i.e. when you pass `name` in `changeName` method, two references (`name` and `str`) are pointing to same object. later `str` points to some other object. but `name` still is pointing to earlier object.

Comment: since the earlier answers added the reasoning, i tried to show that how it can be changed.

Comment: That's not inferred from your answer content. It would be better to add your comment as first line like *As other people have answered, the exercise is to demonstrate Java is pass by value. However, you can change the behavior of the program by doing...* or something like that.